# Html Bootstrap - wrap bootstrap carousel to fit the image presented

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So, I've got a problem when trying to use a bootstrap example.

I've copied a carousel example from bootstrap's page, and tried to use it in my own project.

However, as seen on the picture - 
[image: My attempt at using carousel]

The carousel is not centered, and the prev/next buttons are going to the far left/right, instead of being over the picture, [as per bootstrap example here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

The code that I'm using is:

```
    <body role="document">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
the navbar on the top of the page</nav>

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SO9y5OH.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1dWsLKB.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GNZb3UZ.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        3
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

        </div>



</body>
```

As I'm not that well-versed in html, could you please tell me, how to fit the thing neatly into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it into .container>.row>.col-sm-12

```
`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- your carousel goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>`
```

Comment: Thank you! :)

Is it possible, however, to make the carousel auto-wrap images/auto-resize itself, if the images in the carousel have variable width?